# how to add padding top in CSS pseudo element class::after

Tags: css, html

I want to add padding top to ::after and want to make it centered.

But it's not happening, this is what I get :

[image]

After using this css :

```
.list-unstyled li::after {
content: url(images/heartborder.png)
text-align:center;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

and this is my HTML CODE :

```html
<li>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">
        <span class="icon-small">
            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div class="details">
                <h5 class="heading">View / Edit Profile</h5>
                <p>You can view or edit your profile from here. Phone no., address, other information etc. etc.</p>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `:after` is set by default to `display: inline` so padding has no effect on it. Change it to `inline-block` or `block` and then it will.

To center it (as requested in comments), use flex on the div as below:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to apply `padding` or `margin`. add `margin:0 auto` to get center.

```css
.list-unstyled li::after {
  content: url(images/heartborder.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">
<span class="icon-small">
 <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <div class="details">
<h5 class="heading">View / Edit Profile</h5>
<p>You can view or edit your profile from here. Phone no., address, other information etc. etc.</p>
</div>
</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thnaks @lokesh But how to make it in center. without using padding left ?

Comment: Didn't miss `content: ' '` as the OP has `content: url()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add semicolon after **content: url(images/heartborder.png)** attribute

OR

I think you need to do like this:

```
.list-unstyled li::after {
    content: url(images/heartborder.png);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```